# Private host with static ip on VMware

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I have an Ubuntu virtual machine that I run on my Windows 7 laptop with VMware player 7.1.0.

Here is the setup:

```
Virtual Machine Settings > Network connection : Bridged.
```

Settings of the Ubuntu VM:

```
/etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
addresse 192.168.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
geteway 192.168.1.1
```

This configuration works perfectly when I am on my network. However when I am working from an hotel, it does not.

Network details from the hotel:

```
IP: 10.199.0.67
Netmask: 255.255.240.0
Gateway: 10.199.0.1
```

Ideally, I would prefer a static ip for the VM which would not need reconfiguration if I am at home, work or in a hotel.
Looks like the host only network connection (access from the laptop only, no Internet access for the VM) is the solution but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd setup ICS on the host between a virtual NIC and the actual network adapter. The hardware adapter will join the hotel network, share the connection to the virtual NIC, which will be the gateway for your virtual guest network.

// Add a virtual NIC

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc708372%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

// Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7

Comment: I was looking for a VMware/Ubuntu reconfiguration.